# How can I make a void-function to a leading?

Tags: flutter, function, dart

can someone help me I am new in Flutter and I don't know how to make an average as leading,

here is my code:

```
void gradePointAverage() {
  setState(() {
    double avg = gradeObjects.fold(0, (avg, element) => avg + element/gradeObjects.length);
    print(avg);
  });
}
```

I tried to make a number average but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  void gradePointAverage() {
  setState(() {
       double sum = gradeObjects.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
       double avg = sum / gradeObjects.length;
    print(avg);
  });
}
```